# Dojo: Enhanced Grid layout options to have sub columns?

Tags: dojo

I am trying to get an enhanced grid to look like:

[image]

As you see though in each row in the table, I will only display information for col1, Col2AA, Col2AB, Col2BA, Col2BB etc

Col2, Col3, Col2A, Col2B etc are just super colmn headers to let the user know what Col2AA is udner.

Anyone have any experiance with Grid Layouts for Dojo?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with an enhanced grid.
If you use dojo 1.7> you may try dgrid instead...

See :

- https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/CompoundColumns
- http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/defining_grid_structures/